# ejs.renderFile in js file got a error

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am new to Node.js. The following code I run in a js file got a error :"'An error occurred: renderFile(siginin.ejs)". Cannot figure why?

```
ejs.renderFile('./views/signin.ejs',function(err, result) {
   if (!err) {
            res.end(result);
   }
   else {
            res.end('An error occurred: renderFile(siginin.ejs)');
            console.log(err);
   }
```

});

errors:

cb is not a function

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:353:12)
at signin (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\routes\home.js:10:6)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
```

i visit this link in browser and got above error:
http://localhost:3000/signin

app.js:

```
var home = require('./routes/home'); //add label
app.get('/signin', home.signin);
```

This is the file of home.js:

home.js

```
/**
* New node file
*/
var ejs = require("ejs");
var mysql = require('./mysql');

function signin(req,res) {

ejs.renderFile('./views/signin.ejs',function(err, result) {
   // render on success
   if (!err) {
            res.end(result);
   }
   // render or error
   else {
            res.end('An error occurred: renderFile(siginin.ejs)');
            console.log(err);
   }
   });

  }


function afterSignIn(req,res)
{
// check user already exists
var getUser="select * from users where username='"+req.param("inputUsername")+"' and password='" + req.param("inputPassword") +"'";
console.log("Query is:"+getUser);

mysql.fetchData(function(err,results){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else 
    {
        if(results.length > 0){
            console.log("valid Login");
            ejs.renderFile('./views/successLogin.ejs', { data: results } , function(err, result) {
                // render on success
                if (!err) {
                    res.end(result);
                }
                // render or error
                else {
                    res.end('An error occurred: renderFile(successLogin.ejs)');
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
        else {    

            console.log("Invalid Login");
            ejs.renderFile('./views/failLogin.ejs',function(err, result) {
                // render on success
                if (!err) {
                    res.end(result);
                }
                // render or error
                else {
                    res.end('An error occurred: renderFile(failLogin.ejs).');
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }  
},getUser);
}
```

Comment: Can you add more of the error? Maybe the stacktrace?

Comment: I just added that to the post.

Comment: Can you provide your `home.js` file, it says its crashing on line 10 of that file. `at signin (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\routes\home.js:10:6)`

Comment: line 10: ejs.renderFile('./views/signin.ejs',function(err, result) {. Do you need the whole file?

Comment: I understand but it says `cb is not a function` so `home.js` must be using `cb` around line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set EJS as a View Engine in Express and use [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) instead of all of this extra code which does the same thing. Your current approach is a lot messier and doesn't leverage some of the better parts of Express, such as [View Engine middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html).

Its simple to get it going in Express

```
// Tell Express to render the views from ./views
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Set EJS as the View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

The above code block will set EJS as the view engine for Express and use it for the `res.render()` function.

Then simply in your route you can do

```
app.get('/signin', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('signin');
});
```

or you could edit your `home.signin()` function

```
signin(req, res) {
  return res.render('signin');
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks. Small thing: I used "the app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');" get error: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
   at new View (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:62:11)
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\Nodejs_Login\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12). Then I use this (app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); )instead, it works.

Comment: @J.C. I've updated my answer to use the `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` approach. If this indeed was the answer and was helpful, mark as the answer and upvote so future readers of this question know that this indeed was the solution

Comment: answer marked. With regard to upvote. the website response "once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score", because i am a new user of stackoverflow. Just need to wait for a while.

Comment: @J.C. No worries, the answer marked is more important for future readers. Glad I was able to help